# Query base on activerecord metadata

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, store

So I have a user object in my rails DB with a metadata column. What I would like to be able to do is query based off of this column...

So I have a `User` which has `User.name` and `User.metadata`. I setup the store so I have:

```
store_accessor :metadata, [:hair_color, :eye_color]
```

If I do `User.first.hair_color` I get `blue` just as I would expect... What doesn't seem to be working is `User.where(hair_color: 'blue')`. How do I query based on metadata?

Comment: If possible, I would avoid using store_accessor for fields you want to search by.  This could be done by making them actual columns on the data base if there is only a small number of globally used attributes.  or by an [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) using a gem like [eav_hashes](https://github.com/iostat/eav_hashes)  if the fields will vary from user to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store arbitrarily complex information (such as metadata seems to be) I would suggest using a JSON column type, which is available in [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) and [Postgre](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html). Here is some info about [saving and querying JSON data in Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json) from the official documentation.

Comment: I forgot to mention the column is already JSON so this is exactly what I needed! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to search like this

```
User.where("metadata like ?", "%#{matadata_key}: #{metadata_value}%")
```

For your example `metadata_key` would be `"hair_color"` and `metadata_value` would be `"blue"`

This will be a very slow search.  Read through [this blog](http://samuelmullen.com/2012/04/activerecord-base-store-pros-cons-usage/) for more details